# Spring security namespace configuration: cannot put authentication-provider inside a authentication-manager

Tags: spring-security, xml-namespaces

I‘m start to use spring security to protect my project, but I have a problem with the namespace configuration. Here is my applicationContext-security.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">


    <http>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**/query/**" access="none" />
    </http>

    <http>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**/edit/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <form-login />
        <logout />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="jimi" password="jimispassword" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
                <user name="bob" password="bobspassword" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>


</beans:beans>
```

These code are copied from the reference of spring security. However, the IDE gives following errors:

1, Element authentication-manager doesn't have required attribute alias.

2, Element authentication-provider is not allowed here.

3, Cannot resolve symbol user-service.

4, Cannot resolve symbol user.

What should I do? Thx!

Comment: Use a recent version of Spring Security. Also the fact that the ide gives an error doesn't mean there actually is an error, wouldn't be the first time that Eclipse gives false warnings...

Comment: @M.Deinum  Thanks for your comment. I'm using spring-security-3.2.5 and the IDE I'm using is intellij. However, I'll take your advice and temporarily ignore the error.

Comment: Could be that it is referencing an older xsd version (for whatever reason). Although not recommended you could try to include the version number in the xsd `-3.2.xsd` although it is recommended to use the versionless one.

Comment: @M.Deinum  I tried the     -3.2.xsd before, but it didn't work out.